# How to filter and rename elements in a list of hasmaps with `json_query`

Tags: ansible, json-query

I am trying to filter and rename some elements from a list of hashmaps using `json_query`

I have the following sample data in my ansible facts:

```
"ansible_mounts": [
    {
        "block_used": 136260,
        "uuid": "fa28207c-c4cf-4afd-a2e8-7090c3e4263e",
        "size_total": 2136997888,
        "block_total": 521728,
        "mount": "/disk1",
        "block_available": 385468,
        "size_available": 1578876928,
        "fstype": "xfs",
        "inode_total": 1048576,
        "inode_available": 1048572,
        "device": "/dev/sdb1",
        "inode_used": 4,
        "block_size": 4096,
        "options": "rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota"
    },
    {
        "block_used": 443460,
        "uuid": "f2a3d15f-f63a-4b07-bfe6-aa1fa3366c58",
        "size_total": 3210739712,
        "block_total": 783872,
        "mount": "/mnt/disk2",
        "block_available": 340412,
        "size_available": 1394327552,
        "fstype": "xfs",
        "inode_total": 1572864,
        "inode_available": 1572860,
        "device": "/dev/sdb2",
        "inode_used": 4,
        "block_size": 4096,
        "options": "rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota"
    },
    {
        "block_used": 482382,
        "uuid": "17764e52-0259-4918-b8c6-d4b99041db75",
        "size_total": 10725883904,
        "block_total": 2618624,
        "mount": "/",
        "block_available": 2136242,
        "size_available": 8750047232,
        "fstype": "xfs",
        "inode_total": 5242368,
        "inode_available": 5184047,
        "device": "/dev/sda1",
        "inode_used": 58321,
        "block_size": 4096,
        "options": "rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota"
    }
]
```

Currently I am using the following query:

```
- set_fact:
    mountlist: "{{ ansible_mounts | json_query('{device: [*].device, name: [*].mount, size: [*].size_available}') }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ mountlist }}"
```

And I am getting the following result:

```
"msg": {
  "device": [
    "/dev/sdb1", 
    "/dev/sdb2", 
    "/dev/sda1"
  ], 
  "name": [
    "/disk1", 
    "/mnt/disk2", 
    "/"
  ], 
  "size": [
    1578876928, 
    1394327552, 
    8736772096
  ]
}
```

However, what I expect is:

```
"msg": [
   {
      "name": "/disk1",
      "device": "/dev/sdb1"
      "size": 1578876928
   },
   {
      "name": "/mnt/disk2",
      "device": "/dev/sdb2"
      "size": 1394327552
   },
   {
      "name": "/",
      "device": "/dev/sda1"
      "size": 8736772096
   }
]
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my query and how to change it to obtain the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_query` uses the [`jmespath` library](http://jmespath.org/). You should review the [tutorial](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html), [examples](http://jmespath.org/examples.html) and [specification](http://jmespath.org/specification.html)

In your specific case, the result you get is strictly coherent with the filter you wrote. To get the result you expect, you must modify it. The below task is an example to get the desired result:

```
- name: Filter + Rename elements from my source list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_mounts | json_query('[].{device: device, name: mount, size: size_available}') }}"
```

This is the result using your sample data:

```
TASK [Filter + Rename elements from my source list] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "device": "/dev/sdb1",
            "name": "/disk1",
            "size": 1578876928
        },
        {
            "device": "/dev/sdb2",
            "name": "/mnt/disk2",
            "size": 1394327552
        },
        {
            "device": "/dev/sda1",
            "name": "/",
            "size": 8750047232
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: it worked, however how can i have the output starting with 
`"Somestring": [
{
 "device": "/dev/sdb1",`

Comment: Assign the value to a variable named `Somestring`

Answer (score 0):

*json_query* below does the job

```
- set_fact:
    mountlist: "{{ ansible_mounts|
                   json_query('[*].{mount: mount,
                                   device: device,
                                   size: size_available}')
                                   }}"
```